# Convention for Structuring Angular Interface Files and User Defined Type Guards

Tags: angular, typescript, conventions, convention, file-structure

I am using Interfaces in my Angular 2 project, and also have created User Defined Type Guards:

### grid-metadata.ts

```
export interface GridMetadata {
  activity: string;
  createdAt: object;
  totalReps: number;
  updatedAt: object;
}
```

### grid.service.ts

```
...
    function isGridMetadata(obj: any): obj is GridMetadata {
      [ 'activity', 'createdAt', 'totalReps', 'updatedAt' ].every((prop) => {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) === false) return false;
      });

      return typeof obj.activity === 'string' &&
        obj.createdAt.hasOwnProperty('.sv') &&
        obj.createdAt['.sv'] === 'timestamp' &&
        typeof obj.totalReps === 'number' &&
        obj.updatedAt.hasOwnProperty('.sv') &&
        obj.updatedAt['.sv'] === 'timestamp' ?
          true :
          false;
    }
...
```

What is the convention for storing (i.e. in a file structure) Interfaces; should they be in their own files or in an `interface` or `util` directory or file, for example?

What is the convention for storing shared User Defined Type Guards? Would it make sense to have the Interface and UDTG in the same file (as they are related) or have all UDTGs in a shared module?

I can't find any solid examples as to the best practice or commonly accepted conventions when structuring my project.

Comment: I think the goal is to have each thing in its separate container/file/block/folder. So, have a file with your interface. A file for the class implementing that interface. A file that extends that class (for example), and so on.

Comment: I think this is fairly subjective. I often see people saying that consistency is more important than how you name something or where you put it (within reason).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood well Angular is all about havign each thing in its right place.

That's why we have a structure like:

- +users

  - user.ts
  - user-profile.ts
  - user-dashboard.component.ts
  - user-dashboard.component.html
  - users.service.ts
  - users.module.ts

Where **+users** would be the User's folder.

- `user.ts` could be the `UserInterface`, per say.
- `user-profile.ts` could be the `Class` implements `UserInterface`.
- `user-dashboard.component.ts` could be the User's Dashboard component. The `Class` that maybe extends `UserProfile` class.

And so on...

That's how I saw some OOP project's were structured, and how I interpreted that Angular's devs wanted it to be.